# How to give two different if conditons in one formula field?

Tags: formula-field

I need to put these two if conditions together in one formula field. Can any help me in this.

```
 OR(IF(AND((NSL_Number__c != NULL),(NSL_Number__c != '0')), HYPERLINK("https://c.cs14.visual.force.com/apex/Customer_Signup_Form?id="& Id, "Click to Open Signup Form"), "Signup Form will be available only for NSL Customer"),

IF(AND((Email_Complete__c != true ), ( Signup_Form_Complete__c != true )), HYPERLINK("https://c.cs14.visual.force.com/apex/Customer_Signup_Form?id="& Id, "Click to Open Signup Form"), "Signup Form already submitted for this Account")))
```

Comment: @MikeChale I have updated my question but i am getting an error. Please help me out

Comment: What logic are you really trying to do. Can you just type in plain text how you want this to work? The way you have it written now doesn't make any sense. The OR function needs two booleans and you are returning 2 strings. You can read up on the formulas here - https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking to do:

```
IF(
    AND(NOT(ISBLANK(NSL_Number__c)),NSL_Number__c != '0'),
    IF(
        AND(NOT(Email_Complete__c), NOT(Signup_Form_Complete__c)),
        HYPERLINK("https://c.cs14.visual.force.com/apex/Customer_Signup_Form?id="& Id, "Click to Open Signup Form"),
        "Signup Form already submitted for this Account"
    ),    
        "Signup Form will be available only for NSL Customer"
)
```

This will first check if the NSL_Number__c has a value that isn't `0`. If it doesn't, it will automatically change the message to `Signup Form will be available only for NSL Customer`. If that condition is true, it will check to see if Email_Complete__c is NOT true and that Signup_Form_Complete__c is NOT true. If neither of them are true, it will provide the link of `Click to Open Signup Form`. If either of them are true, it will say `Signup Form already submitted for this Account`.

You should read up on [Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions.htm&language=en_US) to get a better idea of the functions that are available.